# Android application Implement daily updates

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I’m hoping this question hasn’t been asked before or that it isn’t too basic, but if it has please let me know and I will delete this question!

I have experience programming in Java but I am fairly new to programming for Android Applications (specifically on Eclipse). I’m trying to help a friend out with his business (which will inadvertently be my first Android app!). All that he wants me to do is develop an application where there will be a daily update with an inspirational image and quote. I’m sure it’s something that is extremely simple, but I’m unsure on how to provide continual updates to an application. Would I put it on a server? Can I upload it to some website (Google Drive, image sharing website, etc.) and somehow tell the app to continually grab the newest one? And then save old images and text onto the phone so they can access it anytime in the future?

If you could point me to source code that I could manipulate that would excellent! I learn best when I can alter existing syntax to see effects. I appreciate the help and hope to hear from you soon!

Would you suggest this to be a good example for me to look off of: http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an update to *the application itself*, just sending new content to it. A trivial REST service calling to an HTTP server can send the information. The Spring Android `RestTemplate` or other similar client-side libraries make consuming REST services easy, and Spring MVC, Jersey, and dozens of other frameworks for Java and other languages can implement the entire server side of this in a few classes.

Comment: Thank you! So after looking at your comment and reviewing it further on this website (http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/08/how-to-create-restful-http-for-android-in-4-easy-steps-using-spring/), this is what I understood: I can use REST to grab data from an HTTP Server (like Dropbox?). Would I use a download interface to grab the actual picture? I'm sorry for the assortment of questions.

Comment: @JaKuzhi Sounds like you just need to read up on how Web browsers work and on basic REST services. There are Spring Getting Started guides that can show you most of what you'd need for the dynamic part.